# GVM does not install products on linux mint

Tags: grails, groovy, gradle, installation, gvm

I have a recent version of GVM - in fact, my entire machine is very recent as I wiped off Windows and installed Linux Mint 17 at the end of May or beginning of June. GVM does not install software, doesn't even create the directory (in the example, no 2.4.2 directory - as you can see, the **mv** fails for this reason). I have had to install the products manually. The "current" points to a non-existent instance if I fail to do so. This has been true of Grails, Groovy and Gradle.

Here is an example:

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ gvm install grails 2.4.2

Downloading: grails 2.4.2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
100  131M  100  131M    0     0  1208k      0  0:01:51  0:01:51 --:--:-- 2092k

Installing: grails 2.4.2
mv: target ‘/home/worldwidewilly/.gvm/grails/2.4.2’ is not a directory
Done installing!

Do you want grails 2.4.2 to be set as default? (Y/n): y

Setting grails 2.4.2 as default.
```

What need I do to not fail on the install? Are there dependencies in Linux that I need install?

EDIT #1 - adding requested ls

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ \ls -la ~/.gvm
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 53 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jul  9 22:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jul  9 07:58 archives
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 ext
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 gaiden
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 glide
drwxr-xr-x  3 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 28 20:54 gradle
drwxr-xr-x  3 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jul  9 08:11 grails
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 griffon
drwxr-xr-x  3 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:27 groovy
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:26 src
drwxr-xr-x  6 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jul  9 08:00 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4096 Jun 15 12:27 var
```

EDIT #2 - adding second second ls

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ ls -la ~/.gvm/grails
total 12K
  524305 drwxr-xr-x  3 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jul  9 08:11 .
59776162 drwxr-xr-x 16 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 15 12:27 ..
19138378 drwxr-xr-x 10 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:09 2.4.1
  524458 lrwxrwxrwx  1 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly   38 Jul  9 08:11 current -> /home/worldwidewilly/.gvm/grails/2.4.2
```

EDIT #3 - showing contents of 2.4.1 directory

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ ls -la ~/.gvm/grails/2.4.1
total 284K
19138378 drwxr-xr-x 10 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:09 .
  524305 drwxr-xr-x  3 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jul  9 08:11 ..
19267975 drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:10 bin
19138379 -rw-r--r--  1 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly   22 Jun 17 09:30 build.properties
19267980 drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:10 conf
19267984 drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly  64K Jun 17 10:10 dist
19138380 -rw-r--r--  1 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly  117 Jun 17 09:20 INSTALL
19138382 drwxr-xr-x 62 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:09 lib
19138381 -rw-r--r--  1 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 171K Jun 17 09:20 LICENSE
19267653 drwxr-xr-x  4 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 09:20 media
19267952 drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:10 plugins
19138931 -rw-r--r--  1 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 2.5K Jun 17 09:20 README
19267876 drwxr-xr-x  2 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:10 scripts
19267676 drwxr-xr-x  5 worldwidewilly worldwidewilly 4.0K Jun 17 10:09 src
```

EDIT #4 - adding zip info

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ which zip
/usr/bin/zip
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~ $ zip -h
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
  The default action is to add or replace zipfile entries from list, which
  can include the special name - to compress standard input.
  If zipfile and list are omitted, zip compresses stdin to stdout.
  -f   freshen: only changed files  -u   update: only changed or new files
  -d   delete entries in zipfile    -m   move into zipfile (delete OS files)
  -r   recurse into directories     -j   junk (don't record) directory names
  -0   store only                   -l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
  -1   compress faster              -9   compress better
  -q   quiet operation              -v   verbose operation/print version info
  -c   add one-line comments        -z   add zipfile comment
  -@   read names from stdin        -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry
  -x   exclude the following names  -i   include only the following names
  -F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder) -D   do not add directory entries
  -A   adjust self-extracting exe   -J   junk zipfile prefix (unzipsfx)
  -T   test zipfile integrity       -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes
  -y   store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
  -e   encrypt                      -n   don't compress these suffixes
  -h2  show more help
```

Comment: can you give us the directory permissions etc.  like `ls -la ~/.gvm` and `ls -la ~/.gvm/grails`

Comment: Can you also show us the content of the 2.4.1 folder please? I suspect it might be a problem with the zip command.

Comment: i was trying to install 2.4.2, but i had exactly the same results with 2.4.1. i created the 2.4.1 folder and installed it manually. that said, i am adding the content.

Comment: Can you please give the output of `which zip` please. After that the output of `zip -h`.

Comment: @MarcoVermeulen I did add the zip info.

Comment: How many free space do you have on that machine? Maybe you need to delete something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had improperly aliased my **mv** command, which caused **mv** to break. See http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=174548 for a deeper explanation.